# Would a Mandatory<T> be a useful addition alongside Guava's Optional<T>?

Tags: java, interface, null, guava, notnull

I was looking at Guava's [Optional](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) class and [its justification](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained), and I wondered whether a similar class to fail-fast when representing values that must not be null would be helpful. I can't find any discussion of this idea so I thought I'd ask here.

My first attempt would try to stay in the style used by Guava, a `Mandatory<T>`, exposing a static factory `of(T t)`. This method throws `NullPointerException` if called with a null argument.

My particular interest is nailing down the semantics of interface methods in respect of null handling. I think that whether to accept null arguments or not is a design decision that should be specifiable in the interface so that client code can be designed accordingly and can avoid duplicating precondition checking logic. As such, an interface using this class might have methods like

`fire(Mandatory<Employee> employee);`

and a client might call

`fire(Mandatory.of(unfortunateEmployee));`

I suspect that the Mandatory type would be quite easy to find using aspects and the like to hook in further checks before invocation if it was absolutely vital that such marked method arguments should not be null.

I've also considered annotation-based approaches such as `fire(@NotNull Employee employee)` but the implementations I've seen require additional wiring up of validators.

So, the questions... does this idea exist anywhere already? If not, have I missed something obvious that undermines it? Or a better idea to achieve this?

Comment: In general, all method parameters should be mandatory unless they're explicitly documented as being allowed to be null (we use the `@Nullable` annotation to document this) or if there's an overload of the method that simply does not take the parameter (this is a preferable way of making a parameter optional, in my opinion). We definitely don't advocate the use of `Optional<T>` for method parameters, and `Mandatory<T>` would have the same issues optional does when used as a parameter type, only worse because almost all parameters would need to use it.

Comment: Note: Optional is now included in Java 8. http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/03/16/java-8-tutorial/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
fire(Mandatory<Employee> employee);
```

If you had a method with this signature, you could still call `fire(null)`; it'd just be that you'd have a `null` of type `Mandatory<Employee>` instead of type `Employee`.  You haven't actually improved safety at all; you've just added a redundant layer of wrapping.

If you want to enforce that a parameter is required, good practice is to use e.g. `Preconditions.checkNotNull` as the first thing in your method to immediately throw a `NullPointerException` if the value is null.

Answer (score 1):

> adding a Mandatory.of method that throws NPE

Using your T variable will already throw a NullPointerException, so what's the point?

> How to specify that a parameter is required as part of the contract?

Javadoc has been used for this for a long time.

> Yeah, but I want to enforce it.

You have too much time on your hands. That aside...

`@NotNull` is the "new way". You can use AOP to wire not-null validation automatically for the desired methods. Here are a couple of great implementations:

http://blog.solidcraft.eu/2010/09/getting-rid-of-null-parameters-with.html
http://janistoolbox.typepad.com/blog/2009/12/aopvalidationnotnull.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment+edit. Counters: 1) it might not throw NPE, depends what the code does and no guarantees about where it will be thrown. Sometimes a long way from where the problem needs to be fixed! 2) Given that I can tell the compiler what should not be nullable, why would I deliberately leave it for people to spend time, forget about and screw up? 3) validators and AOP need libraries to implement them, provide no guarantees that they'll be enforced at runtime and have a learning curve - the Optional-style approach is plain old Java and has its limitations and benefits.